# Java JPA2 Predicate

Tags: java, jpa

I am using Java8 and JPA2.

I would like to add a predicate to a where clause.

I have the following code:

```
@Override
public List<Job> findById(String ids, Integer type) {

    String[] args = ids.split(",");
    Set<String> idSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(args));

    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Job> query = builder.createQuery(Job.class);
    Root<Job> post = query.from(Job.class);
    CriteriaQuery<Job> criteria = query.select(post);
    criteria.where(post.get("id").in(idSet));
    //criteria.where(post.get("type").in(type));  <=== how do I do an equals
    TypedQuery<Job> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
    List<Job> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

As you can see, I use a `criteria` object and have a `where` clause that filters on "ids" in the id set.

I would like to add an addition filter to the where clause, but am not sure how to. I would like to add a clause where column "type" equals the value in the `type` Integer object.

i.e.

```
where id in [...] and type = 1
```

Any advise appreciated.

Comment: how to what? have 2 where clauses? pass both in to the where() method. Or use _builder.and_. If you mean the equals part ... _builder.equal()_

Comment: Asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12199937/212224 a quick google search came up with a lot of examples of different ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Criteria API with multiple parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199433/jpa-criteria-api-with-multiple-parameters)

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397347/jpa-fully-dynamic-and-multi-level-criteria-api