# Best way of creating complex dynamic queries using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

What is the best way for creating dynamic queries using Spring Data JPA?

I want to create custom projection of many tables joined together in many different ways (5-10) for performance reasons. Something simillar to criteria, and projections in previous versions of hibernate.

For example:
I have 6 **tables**: `A, B, C, D, E, F`.
`A`, `B` and `C` are always joined together (`ABC`) and create 'result'.
Tables `D`, `E`, `F` are are joined to `ABC` only when user fills certain search fields. User might search by any of `D,E,F` column, or all of them at once.

I want to achieve projection like this: Result(`A.id, A.name, B.code, C.description`).

I don't want to use `@Query` **annotation** because there's a lot of different possibilites how these tables can be joined.

Comment: Show us what have you tried yet. The question in current form is broad and may attract opinionated answers.

Comment: Use a Specification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397347/jpa-fully-dynamic-and-multi-level-criteria-api/40397632#40397632

Comment: I was trying specification, cause it would be the best option for it, but  unfortunately it didn't work.
Now I'll give a shot to http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections.remodelling-data
And then http://stackoverflow.com/a/30366582/6651146